# Using Google Spreadsheet as DB for apps

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use Google spreadsheets to store data online so multiple people can enter and maintain data, then publish or export (csv, xls, ods) the sheet for their application. What is the easiest way to process the sheet? If the data can be accessed as a link the updates could be immediately reflected in the client's app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article [Data Scraping Wikipedia with Google Spreadsheets](http://ouseful.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/data-scraping-wikipedia-with-google-spreadsheets/) discusses using Google spreadsheets as an application platform.

It already has features that allow you to share the spreadsheet with multiple editors, as well as the ability to define forms that you can invite people to fill out who's results will be entered into the spreadsheet as a row.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case its still vaguely of interest 5 months later, there is a SQL-like wrapper language for Google Spreadsheets at:

http://gqlx.twyst.co.za

Its very much an alpha release - but maybe its of some use or perhaps the code could give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I am clear on your requirements, you want to store your data online in a Google Spreadsheet where multiple people can access that right? Then you want an app to use that data? Correct me if I am wrong.

It is possible to have Google spreadsheet as a database and the client app can directly access that data through APIs - spreadsheet APIs . If you want a simple link where people can go and update - you can also have a web app using google apps scripting. very simple to use and would solve your purpose too , why to export your data to ods, xls, csv, make your app directly over Google Spreadsheet. Would be maintainable too.